# Como usar separador horizontal en recycler view? Android Studio

Tags: android, vistas

Estoy usando un código muy **simple** para separar las vistas en el **Recycler View**, que me funciona solo para los recyclers **verticales**. Por algún extraño motivo, **no me funciona** para el recycler **horizontal**.

**Adjunto el código del separador vertical:**

```
DividerItemDecoration didv = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), 
DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
didv.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_recycler_resultados));
```

Para el separador horizontal, solamente reemplazo donde dice "VERTICAL" por "HORIZONTAL"

**Adjunto el código:**

```
DividerItemDecoration didv = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL);
didv.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_recycler_resultados));
```

Luego, **aplico** el separador en el recycler View:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(didv);
```

**Adjunto el código xml de las vistas del recycler**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_recycler_filtros"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_buscar_fragment_inicio"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adjunto el código xml del drawable "divider_recycler_resultados**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<size android:height="2.5dp"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

</shape>
```

Eso es todo, repito que no me funciona para los recyclers horizontales. Al aplicarlo, se genera una línea por debajo de las vistas del recycler horizontal, como si estuviese separando en forma vertical. Agradecería muchisimo la respuesta!

Comment: ¿ El layout tiene definida algún tipo de orientación, como android:orientation="horizontal" ?

Comment: Si, es horizontal. Edito la pregunta adjuntando el código XML...

Comment: Estas de alguna forma cambiando programaticamente entre orientaciones, me refiero de vertical a horizontal ?

Comment: Nop. No lo estoy haciendo.

Comment: podrias subir divider_recycler_resultados? quizas este ahi el problema, tambien serviria una captura de como se ve el divider cuando no te funciona como esperas

Comment: Ya agregué el xml del divider :)